# Remove eject button from finder

Tags: finder, eject

I accidentally ejected an external drive in the finder, is there an option to hide or remove/disable eject button from finder?

Comment: Let me take a crack at this, Daniel.  

"I **don't** want to accidentally eject an external drive when I'm in the Finder, is there an option to hide or remove eject button from Finder windows?"  

Is this correct, @IAmJulianAcosta?

Comment: defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitEject true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command below to edit the com.apple.finder preference.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitEject true
```

that will set it for the current user, to set it system wide use

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitEject true
```

The eject button will still show in finder but will not do anything when pressed.

Comment: Thank you, is possible to do this only for one drive?

Comment: Not that I can think of easily.  If you don't mind opening it from terminal all the time you can hide the external drive and it won't show in finder at all.

Comment: Is it possible to disable ejecting just for one certain drive?

Comment: Thanks, some days (almost every day) I hit the eject button on my keyboard instead of the backspace key, most annoying :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, and suitable for ANY drive is to right-click the drive and  choose "remove from sidebar". That way you can create an alias or navigate to your files from "{username}'s Mac" without messing with any other system configuration.