# Rewrite 'eject remove' command

Tags: terminal, finder, eject

I used the commands:

`defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitEject true` and
`sudo defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitEject true` (as stated on this page - [Remove eject button from finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157589/remove-eject-button-from-finder))

The command prevented the 'eject' button from working, however i want to undo this command...

Can someone rewrite the command to undo this, so that my eject button can work again?

Comment: Try `false` instead

Answer (score 1):

To reverse any Boolean command, just type the inverse property, so...

true becomes false, one becomes zero

`defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitEject false`

`sudo defaults write com.apple.finder ProhibitEject false`

Comment: Thanks for that... Is there any way to stop eject from working on one drive. I have a SD card that i use for storage and i keep accidentally pressing eject on it... So is there any method to prevent the eject from working on that drive?

Comment: I didn't know Eject would affect anything other than the DVD tray. it doesn't here. SD cards, RAM disks, external drives all must be right-click/ejected, or Cmd/E